# Dadas 4 coordenadas, ¿cómo puedo generar un rectángulo?

Tags: c#

Qué tal,

Estoy creando una aplicación en C# que toma una imagen y con AForge detecto automáticamente la figura, después de esto tiene que contar los pixeles de cierto color dentro de ella. El asunto es que me retorna las 4 coordenadas de las esquinas, pero no siempre están en orden.
Quisiera saber si hay alguna forma de generar un `Rectangle` o de recorrer los pixeles que están dentro de esas 4 coordenadas.

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
BlobCounter blobCounter = new BlobCounter();
            blobCounter.FilterBlobs = true;
            blobCounter.MinWidth = 500;
            blobCounter.MinHeight = 500;
            blobCounter.ProcessImage((Bitmap)pbPattern.Image);
            Blob[] blobs = blobCounter.GetObjectsInformation();
            Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(pbPattern.Image);

            foreach (Blob blob in blobs)
            {
                List<IntPoint> points = blobCounter.GetBlobsEdgePoints(blob);
                List<IntPoint> corners;
                SimpleShapeChecker simpleShapeChecker = new SimpleShapeChecker();
                simpleShapeChecker.IsQuadrilateral(points, out corners);
                System.Drawing.Point[] cornerPoints = ToPointsArray(corners);
                graphics.DrawPolygon(new Pen(Brushes.Green, 10), cornerPoints);
                //graphics.DrawRectangle(new Pen(Brushes.Green, 10), cornerPoints[0].X, cornerPoints[0].Y, cornerPoints[1].X - cornerPoints[0].X, cornerPoints[2].Y - cornerPoints[0].Y);
            }

            pbPattern.Refresh();
            graphics.Dispose();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para cualquier rectángulo, un vértice cualquiera estará conectado con los dos vértices más próximos<sup>1</sup>.

Así pues:

- Coges cualquier vértice V0.
- Calculas la distancia a los otros tres<sup>2</sup>.
- Identificas el más lejano VL, y los otros dos (V1 y V2, da igual cuál es cuál)
- El rectángulo será  V0->V1->VL->V2->V0

---

<sup>1</sup> La demostración se deja como ejercicio para el alumno. Pista: Teorema de Pitágoras. :-p

<sup>2</sup> Para dos vértices, separados horizontalmente por Dx y verticalmente por Dy, la distancia es: raíz cuadrada(Dx<sup>2</sup> + Dy<sup>2</sup>). De hecho, como solo te interesa saber cuál está más lejos, ni siquiera necesitas sacar la raíz cuadrada.